# Add extension method to List

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
class Student
{
    some code 
}

static class Filter
{
    static void TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
    {
        result = result.FindAll(x=>x.type == type);
    }
}
```

when I use this extension method like

```
    List<Student> a = some code;
    a.TypeFilter("someType");
```

List **a** was not filtered, List should be a reference type, then why **a** didn't change, did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: You have to reassign it. It doesn't modify your original collection but instead creates a new one.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think you mean "You reassign it", not "You have to reassign it". The reassignment inside `TypeFilter` is exactly what's causing the problem here.

Comment: @hvd: right, that too. I was referring to the calling code where only `a.TypeFilter()` was applied but not reassigned to `a`.

Comment: Why do you want reinvent the wheel? For such things there is `LINQ2Objects`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Ah, okay, I don't think that part is a problem, I think the point of `TypeFilter` is supposed to be that it modifies the list in place, so the caller code wouldn't have to use any assignment. But your approach would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `RemoveAll`:

```
static void TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
{
    result.RemoveAll(x=>x.type != type);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's why you;re not seeing the results:

```
static void TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
{
    result = result.FindAll(x=>x.type == type);
}

List<Student> a = some code;
a.TypeFilter("someType");
```

Parameters by defualt are passed by value.  `result` is now a local variable that references a list.  When you call `FindAll` - you get back a *new* reference - the original list that `result` (and `a`) reference is unchanged.

When you reassign the result bask to `result`, `result` now references the new object, and the link back to `a` is broken.  `a` is unchanged through all of this.

Most Linq methods return a new object instead of modifying the passed in object.  If you followed that pattern your method would be

```
static List<Student> TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
{
    return result.FindAll(x=>x.type == type);
}
```

and the usage would be:

```
List<Student> a = some code;
a = a.TypeFilter("someType");
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant assign it this way try this:

```
static List<Student> TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
    {
       return result.FindAll(x=>x.type == type);
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
List<Student> a = some code;
List<Student> filteredStudentList = a.TypeFilter("someType");
```

Answer (score 0):

A is a reference type but a new List was created when FindAll was called.  FindAll is a function that returns a new List.  It is equivalent to the foolow method:

```
List<Student> FindAll (List<Student> students, string filter){
    List<Student> newList = new List<Student>();

    foreach(var student in students){
        if(filter == student.type)
            newList.Add(student);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

If you want to use the return value then you need to capture a reference to the return value by creating a variable:

var filteredStudents = students.TypeFilter("someFilter");

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to the `this` pointer in a reference method, and any method taking a parameter cannot assign to it without making it a `ref` parameter, thus the `List` produced by your code can't be assigned to `result` the way you've described.

Since it is a `List`, you could iterate through and remove items instead of replacing the pointer.

```
static void TypeFilter(this List<Student> result, string type)
{
    foreach(var s in result
        .Except(result.FindAll(x => x.type == type))
        .ToArray())  // VERY Important - modifying a list while iterating through it will throw an exception!
    { result.remove(s); }
}
```